# how to show 4 digits after decimal in shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-activemerchant

```
{% assign dvtprice = currentvariant.price %}

{% assign dvtpriceprat = currentvariant.price | times :20 | dividedby :100 %}
```

Example: if product price is 20.33 , then Vat= (20.33*2)/100=4.066

Answer (score 1):

I think that this was the way - change `times: 20` to `times: 20.00`.

By the way your `dividedby` is wrong it should be `divided_by`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with Shopify.  The core code handles prices to two decimal places, so it will round if appropriate for embedded taxes.

Answer (score -1):

example:

Input
{{ 183.3574456 | round: 4 }}

Output
183.3674